# Insert a new column in existing table

Tags: mysql

If we have already a table then we can not create new... Please share the solution to add new column in existing table. the new column should have alphanumeric and auto increment like "NEWID001, NEWID002, NEWID003 ....". we have one column already in our table as SNO with auto incremental function but it is only for numeric value.
query should be for insert only.
Thanks

Comment: You can use a trigger to add the column.

Comment: You want to add columns to a table with names that automatically count upwards? Or you want to add columns to a table that use `AUTO_INCREMENT` in their definition?

Comment: i am new in this. could you please share any link OR URL to read more about it to know how it will work and how to run query.

Comment: i want to generate a booking ID with auto increment function. but i have already use serialNo column with auto increment and as primary key.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `hostel`  ADD `bookingID` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL  AFTER `sno`,  ADD   UNIQUE  `bookingINDEX` (`bookingID`(11)) USING BTREE;
can i use like this?